# ADO.NET MVC Tutorial (with LINQ to SQL) question about schema changes

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, model-view-controller, ado.net, schema

So I'm working through the new scottgu wrox book, and I create a couple tables. Then (per the tutorial) I use linq to sql to build my Models, DataCOntext, Repository, etc. (It's pretty clear that LINQ to SQL seems to be "the Microsoft Way" to generate models and similar classes from schemas.)

Then I find I've neglected to include one of the columns in one of the tables, so I bring up the table designer and add it.

None of the products from LINQ to SQL seem to notice, and I can't find any obvious way (right-click, properties, etc.) to  bring things back into alignment - F5 just tells me I'm missing a property (of course).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have to delete the table from the linqtosql designer and re-add it.